# How to Disable Content Warning Dialog for Logged in users

Tags: plugin-development

The plugin is this :https://wordpress.org/plugins/content-warning-v2/

and I dont want to show it for logged-in users.

Plugin developer told me:  https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-dont-show-this-box-to-logged-in-users/#post-8411866

> Basically instead of checking for post ID, look for if the user is logged in.

On this code:

```
/**
 * Maybe Show Dialog
 * @param  bool $bool    Default true
 * @param  WP_Post  $post_ob A WP_Post object
 * @return bool           True to show the dialog, false to hide it.
 */
function maybe_show_dialog( $bool = true, $post_ob = null ) {
    if ( isset( $post_obj->ID ) && 1 == $post_obj->ID ) {
        return false;
    }

    return $bool;
}
add_filter( 'cwv3_should_gate', 'maybe_show_dialog', 10, 2 );
```

So, how can I do that? How to change looking for post id php code to users logged in on the above code?

Comment: `if ( isset( $post_obj->ID ) && 1 == $post_obj->ID ) {` is the bit checking post ID, I see you mention your PHP skills are weak, but any answer you get here will be a technical answer assuming basic PHP skills

Comment: How can I change that code to logged-in users?

Comment: if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {   is that this?

Answer (score 0):

To check if an user is logged you can check with `is_user_logged_in()` that will only return true or false. You can combine the statement with `get_current_user_id()`, if the return value is 0, the user is not log.

```
if(is_user_logged_in() && get_current_user_id()!=0 && isset( $post_obj->ID ) && 1 == $post_obj->ID){
    return false;
}
return $bool;
```